# Identify in a series the column with the maximum value for each row of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

Suppose we have the following dataframe :

**Source Dataframe**

```
    A   B   C
0  55   9  96
1  69  86   5
2  30  63  12
3  79  52  31
```

I would like to identify in a series the column with the maximum value for each row of a dataframe.
So the expected result would be :

**Target Dataframe**

```
  MAX
0   C
1   B
2   B
3   A
```

**Dataframe to start with**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [55, 69, 30, 79],
        'B': [9, 86, 63, 52],
        'C': [96, 5, 12, 31]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Due to many bugs, I do not have time to solve this lovely problem, so I would really appreciate if someone provides me with an efficient way of doing the job.

Thanks

Comment: `df.idxmax(axis=1)`

Comment: The dupe is the very first result from googling "pandas column with the maximum value for each row of a dataframe"